# Proving that the quotient $\ell^\infty/c_0$ is not reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, reflexive-space

Let $\ell^\infty$ be the space of bounded sequences with the maximum norm and $c_0$ the space of sequences that have limit $0$ with the same norm. I use the notation $E^*$ for the dual of a normed space $E$.

I know that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$, that $c_0^{**}=\ell^\infty$, and that both $c_0$ and $\ell^\infty$ are not reflexive. How can I prove that $\ell^\infty/c_0$ is not reflexive?

My best guess has been using that a space is reflexive iff its dual is reflexive. The dual of the quotient is $(\ell^\infty/c_0)^*=c_0^\perp$, the orthogonal of $c_0$ in the dual of $\ell^\infty$ (thanks to David for the correction). This is a closed subspace of $(\ell^\infty)^*$ and $(\ell^\infty)^*$ is also not reflexive, but I don't think this implies that $c_0^\perp$ is not reflexive. I also tried using the characterization "A Banach space is reflexive iff the unit ball is weakly compact" but I haven't been able to prove that the ball isn't weakly compact.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwikhduX4LT1AhXTnWoFHReTAbU4ChAWegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fjournals%2Fproc%2F1972-036-02%2FS0002-9939-1972-0308748-7%2FS0002-9939-1972-0308748-7.pdf&usg=AOvVaw08SZOxtqzJ9oH1VFM8C66Q) (Theorem 2.3) contains a proof.

Comment: The dual you mention lives in $\ell_\infty^*$, not $\ell_1$ (and annihilates the copy of $c_0$ in $\ell_\infty$).